# Kibana DataTable Visualization doesnt show message.keyword when having a template

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I use a hosted elk stack installation in the elastic cloud.
There I want to show a **DataTable Visualization** shows how often which message occurred.

For this, I create a new visualization and choose the Aggregation on `Terms` and as field I choose `message.keyword`.

Now depending on the message template the message.keyword isn't resolve

If the document looks like this:

```
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2018-09-14T06:52:49.6874915+00:00",
    "level": "Information",
    "messageTemplate": "Logger Started",
    "message": "Logger Started",
```

The message is aggregated and shown

but if the MessageTemplate and message are defined like this

```
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2018-09-14T07:08:58.6798262+00:00",
    "level": "Warning",
    "messageTemplate": "{shortKey} Invalid steps",
    "message": "\"ABC\" Invalid steps"
```

the message is not resolved / missing.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Just a side node the data is logged form a .net application using the Serlog ElasticSearch sink